# Spring project with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, spring-tool-suite

I'm using Spring Tool Suite (STS) [Version: 3.1.0.RELEASE] to make Spring project using Spring 3 + Hibernate. I want to use eclipse for that.

What to do? What eclipse plugin should be installed in eclipse for making Spring project?

Comment: which version of eclipse you are using?

Comment: Spring Tool Suite is built on top of Eclipse. So anything you can do in Eclipse you can do in STS. So what exactly was the question?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/how-to-install-spring-ide-in-eclipse/

Comment: @subodh: I am using the following eclipse version:

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

Comment: @ApacheFan: I don't want to use STS separately. In eclipse I want to make Spring project. What plugin I need to add on eclipse for that?

Answer (score 1):

By Eclipse Marketplace:

1. Open eclipse --> Help --> Eclipse Marketplace
2. Search by keyword  "STS"
3. Click Install button on "Spring Tool Suite (STS) for Eclipse Indigo (3.7)" section
4. Follow the eclipse instruction

Comment: I installed STS in eclipse successfully by following the above steps

Answer (score 0):

The following is the Classic way:

In Eclipse IDE: Click “Help” -> “Install New Software…”. Type “http://springide.org/updatesite” to access the Spring IDE update site.

Select all the Spring IDE features you want to install. And wait as it needs - that's it

Comment: I tried above, but I found an error as:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: SpringSource Tool Suite Runtime Error Analysis Support 2.6.0.201103161000-RELEASE (com.springsource.sts.runtimeerroranalysis.feature.group 2.6.0.201103161000-RELEASE)
Missing requirement: SpringSource Tool Suite Runtime Error Analysis Support 2.6.0.201103161000-RELEASE (com.springsource.sts.runtimeerroranalysis.feature.group 2.6.0.201103161000-RELEASE) requires 'com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.jira.feature.group 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Answer (score 0):

If you already using STS you can easily create Spring projects - no additional plugins needed.
*STS is Eclipse with Spring plugins added - don't waste your time doing it manually.*

1. In the main menu select File > New > Other...
2. Type "Spring" in the search bar.
3. Select "Spring Template Project", click "Next"
4. Open "Persistence" node and select "Simple Spring Hibernate Utility Project" and follow the wizard.

After wizard is done you are going to have simple Spring/Hibernate project in your workspace.

**UPDATE:**

Spring projects are simple java projects and be created easily using just Maven. Add m2e plugin if you don't have it yet and add required spring jars as dependencies in your pom.xml file.

M2E comes preinstalled with STS, but can be installed into any Eclipse installation.
More information about using m2e can be found at http://www.sonatype.org/m2eclipse

Comment: Yes, Your instruction is helpful to create a Spring Hibernate project on STS. But I want to switch to eclipse from STS. In eclipse I want to create Spring Hibernate project.